# Throughput Volume Query in Application Insights

Tags: performance, azure, monitoring, azure-application-insights, dashboard

i am trying to get Throughput(Volume) metrics by using below query

```
requests
// additional filters can be applied here
| where timestamp > ago(24h)
| where client_Type != "Browser"
| summarize count() by bin(timestamp, 5m)
| extend request='Volume'
// render result in a chart
| render timechart
```

So my question is for Volume do we use Count() or sum(itemCount) ? Which one of these is more Accurate to get Volume(Throughput) details per interval ??

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to use sum(itemCount). Then this metric will be correct for sampled applications (by default adaptive sampling will kick in when number of telemetry items exceeds 5/sec).